# Flutter find index in a list which is contains spesific variable

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I have a list which is created with a json model.
List has items like = [id,viewers(list),streamers(list) ... etc]

I need to find correct index which is list has a spesific string.

List has a item > "id" = 29392392_23232 (etc) .

I tried this.

```
 int historyIndex =viewerModel.viewerList.where((element) => ["id"] ==pathList[index].path.substring(65, 97).toString() );
```

But im getting error like this.

```
"A value of type 'Iterable<StoryModel?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.\nTry changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'int'.",
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.where` method finds and returns all items in the list that fulfill a specific condition, if you want to find the index of the first item that fulfills the condition, you can use `indexWhere` instead.

Literally just change `where` to `indexWhere` in your code

```
 int historyIndex =viewerModel.viewerList.indexWhere((element) => element["id"] ==pathList[index].path.substring(65, 97).toString() );
```

Comment: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
Im getting this error and my nullchecks not working for it

Comment: I did that but still return -1 even list has string that i looked for

Comment: int? historyIndex = widget.viewers?.indexWhere(
                      (element) => ((element as dynamic)['id']) == story.url.substring(66, 97).toString());

Now its saying there is no thing []('id') in your model. But it is exist

Comment: These should be pretty obvious fixes, it has to do with the type of your model, change this `((element as dynamic)['id'])` to this: `element?.id`

Comment: I managed to fix my problem . But forgot to comment here. Yes this is the correct solution for my problem. Thank you.